# libcups2-dev won't install because of libcupsimage2-dev

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian, cups, printer

I'm running Raspbian and want to install [Splix](http://splix.ap2c.org/), for which I need libcupsimage2-dev, so I installed it using apt-get, which yielded an error saying it has a dependency on "libcupsimage2-dev" which won't be installed. When I run "sudo apt --fix-broken install" it yields me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcupsimage2-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcupsimage2-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 212 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/18.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 66.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Invalid archive member header cgnTrol.tar,xz  1566333;93$  ( 
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{zstlz4gzxzbz2lzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libcupsimage2-dev_2.2.10-6+deb10u1_armhf.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: file '/var/cache/apt/archives/libcupsimage2-dev_2.2.10-6+deb10u1_armhf.deb' is corrupt - bad archive header magic
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libcupsimage2-dev_2.2.10-6+deb10u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcupsimage2-dev_2.2.10-6+deb10u1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The archive is corrupt, you should delete it and try again:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libcupsimage2-dev_2.2.10-6+deb10u1_armhf.deb
```